# Basic Proposition of Cardinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

**Definition**. A cardinal is an ordinal which it is not in bijection with any smaller ordinal.

**Notation**. $|X|$ means that cardinal of $X$.

Proposition 1. Let $w$ be an ordinal. Then $|w+1|=w.$

Proposition 2. $|w^2|=w$.

I couldn't understand proposition 1 and 2, can you explain that why $|w+1|=w$ and $|w^2|=w$.

Comment: It should assume that $w$ is an infinite ordinal.  Then you can find a bijection between $w+1$ and $w$ and another between $w^2$ and $w$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ahh yess!! Thanks for comment!

Comment: As standalone statements, they are not true. They should be modified in either of the following ways: a) add "infinite" next to "ordinal" and substitute all "$=w$" with "$=\lvert w\rvert$"; b) substitute all "ordinal" with "inifinite cardinal".